# Drag and drop function not allowing desired selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using the below code to make the images on my site draggable, but I can not choose the selector I wish to use. Although the images are draggable while using '.photo', it uses a bounding box with a larger size than the image and I would rather use 'img' or '.img1' & '.img2'.

Also since I started using this code the lightbox function is triggered every time I release the image instead of only on solid clicks.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.photo').drag(function( ev, dd ){
        $( this ).css({
            top: dd.offsetY,
            left: dd.offsetX
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML used to place in an image

```
<div class="photo">
<a href="http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/3/images/full/011.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img class="img1" src="http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/3/images/011.png"/></a></div>
```

I have used Draggable for this effect but that led to a weird issue in Chrome/Safari that I couldn't solve so I chose a new approach.

Comment: I'm curious; what was the Chrome/Safari issue with `Draggable`?

Comment: The dragging movement only works properly with the images that are visible in the window on first load. Anything else gets shot to the top of the page when you attempt to drag it. Any idea how I could focus on fixing that instead?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop
You can actually test it here. If you drag the image down, forcing the window to scroll with you, release it and attempt to drag it again. The behavior is a little different but I'm it's a product of the same flaw.

Comment: Wow. Ouch... I hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: Yeah it forced me to switch over this drag function, which created these two new problems that I've been struggling with for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1684510.aspx/1?jQuery+Drag+and+Drop+Database) may help you

OR

Check jQuery UI Droppable

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: My apologies I will take care of it. I am new at that time on stackoverflow.